# Exporting and Importing Jenkins Pipeline script approvals

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a significant set of Groovy pipeline scripts for our Jenkins build process.  I am in the process of moving those scripts onto another instances, and would like to replicate the set of approved scripts that were not originally white listed.

Is it possible to export the list of approved signatures and import them into another instance?

The only other solution I have is to constantly run and rerun the scripts and approving each signature as it breaks the build.  Since the scripts are quite complex, and not every run is guaranteed to hit each line, this is not going to be a quick process.

The other option would be to create a master 'white list' script which runs all the currently non-approved scripts again and again until all instances had been approved.

Neither of these options is great, so I'm hoping for a simple import/export to avoid having to do this work altogether, but I certainly can't see an option available to be in the UI.

Cheers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not believe there is import/export functionality by default but maybe there's a plugin that'll do it.

If you have access to the directory Jenkins' is installed or runs in you should be able to find the `scriptApproval.xml` file.

If you explore that you'll find `approvedScriptHashes` and `approvedSignatures` etc. You can lift this file entirely and paste it in the new instance or copy across the specifics you need (either way you'll need a restart).

Looks like there's an open request for this sort of functionality [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22660)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll see if I can use that file for the time being

Comment: It's interesting that after I copy/pasted the 'approvedSignatures' xml elements from one server to another, the destination server (Jenkins v2.121.3) UI for 'In-process Script approval' did not change! I expected to see the signatures appearing in the 'Signatures already approved:' text area, but this did not happen even after I restarted the server. I'm still uncertain as to whether the pasted signatures are allowed (until I run into a blocked signature )

Comment: Update of my earlier uncertainty: After running a job that made use of the pasted approved  signatures, the UI got updated with those that were approved. So it seems that copying and pasting approved signatures works!

Comment: @IoannisK.Moutsatsos I hadn't realised that the approved screen will only be updated on running a related script - thanks for info.